# Como evito que se escriba punto en primer posicion de datagridview c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Alguien me puede ayudar quiero evitar que se escriba un punto de inicio como se ve aquí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código con el que valido para que solo entren números y un punto pero quiero evitar que el punto sea en la primer posición.

```
  private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
        dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dText_KeyPress);
        dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dText_KeyPress);
    }

    void dText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {           
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición `(sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1` tiene un error lógico, si no hay ningún punto en el textbox el resultado será falso y no ejecutará la instrucción `e.Handled = true;` y por eso aceptará el punto en la primera posición.

Puedes evaluar que la longitud del campo sea igual a 0 para que no permita el ingreso de puntos en la primera posición

```
if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.Length == 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```